# Dispose Entity DbContext in WebForm ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I was using 1 class to provide data to my webpage. Since I changed to 2 class i got error

```
The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.
```

My two class derived from Database
    public class SezonB : Database
    public class Siatkowka : Database

There aren't own concstructor (by default is calling default constructor)

I don't know why 1 class with derived from another instanceDispose DbContext of another instance. After loaded PobierzRanking() DbContext is closed for get PobierzSezony()

Here are my classes.

My base class for create db instance

```
public abstract class Database : IDisposable
{
    #region Fields

    /// <summary>
    ///     Tutaj jest przechowywana lokalna baza danych
    /// </summary>
    protected PabLeweEntities Plentities;

    #endregion // Fields

    #region Constructor

    protected Database()
    {
        Plentities = new PabLeweEntities();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
            if (Plentities != null)
            {
                Plentities.Dispose();
                Plentities = null;
            }
    }

    ~Database()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    #endregion // Construtor
}
```

On website are 3 ObjectDataSource

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="PobierzRanking"
                                          TypeName="PlazowkaLewe.Model.Siatkowka">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="sortExpression" Type="String" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:ObjectDataSource>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource6" runat="server" SelectMethod="PobierzSezony"
                                              TypeName="PlazowkaLewe.Model.SezonB">
                            <SelectParameters>
                                <asp:Parameter Name="sortExpression" Type="String" />
                            </SelectParameters>
                        </asp:ObjectDataSource>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource2" runat="server" SelectMethod="PobierzTurnieje"
                                              TypeName="PlazowkaLewe.Model.Siatkowka">
                            <SelectParameters>
                                <asp:Parameter Name="sortExpression" Type="String" />
                                <asp:SessionParameter Name="idTurnieju" SessionField="id_turnieju2" Type="Int32"/>
                            </SelectParameters>
                        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

After I removed IDisposable interface every works.

Comment: Have you tried removing the finalizer?  It is recommended that you don't even create one for your classes.

Comment: @Justin, Yes. Without finalizer it work's properly.

Comment: Just to confirm, removing the finalizer resolved this issue, correct?

Comment: @Justin, I confirm. Removing ~Database() resolved the issue.